# Rock, paper, scissors. Can't seem to get buttons working. (beginner)

Tags: javascript

I'm making a Rock, Paper, Scissors game. Everything worked in the console, so now I'm working on making buttons work. I've selected each of the buttons and added an event listener too, but I'm breaking my head against the implementation of it.

When I click "start", the game starts, but when I click - for example - the "rock" button, it immediately runs the game 5 times with "rock" as the only playerPick. I tried breaking it down: the loop runs 5 times and doesn't stop and wait for a second click.

It probably has to do with the positioning of my different functions.

Thanks in advance for anyone reading this!

```js
var scorePlayer = 0;
    var scoreComputer = 0;
    let displayPlayerScore = document.getElementById("playerScore");
    let displayComputerScore = document.getElementById("computerScore");
    let rockButton = document.getElementById("rock");
    let paperButton = document.getElementById("paper");
    let scissorsButton = document.getElementById("scissors");
    let startButton = document.getElementById("startGame");
    let playerPick = "";
    
    let computerPlay = () => {
      const pick = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
      computerPick = pick[Math.floor(Math.random() * pick.length)];
    };
    
    let playerPlay = () => {
      rockButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
        return playerPick = "rock";
      });
      
      paperButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
       return playerPick = "paper";
      });
      
      scissorsButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
        return playerPick = "scissors";
      });
      // playerPick = prompt("what's your pick?").toLowerCase();
    };
    
    // game is played for 5 rounds max
    let game = () => {
      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        playerPlay();
        computerPlay();
        let playRound = (p, c) => {
          if (p === c) {
            console.log("=================")
            console.log("Draw. PLAY AGAIN!");
            console.log("=================")
          } else if (c === "rock" && p === "paper") {
            scorePlayer += 1;
            displayPlayerScore.textContent = scorePlayer;
            console.log("=================")
            console.log(`${playerPick} beats ${computerPick}. \n Player score: ${scorePlayer}`);
            console.log("=================")
          } else if (c === "paper" && p === "scissors") {
            scorePlayer += 1;
            displayPlayerScore.textContent = scorePlayer;
            console.log("=================")
            console.log("Player wins. Player score: " + scorePlayer);
            console.log("=================")
          } else if (c === "scissors" && p === "rock") {
            scorePlayer += 1;
            displayPlayerScore.textContent = scorePlayer;
            console.log("=================")
            console.log("Player wins. Player score: " + scorePlayer);
            console.log("=================")
          } else if (c === "rock" && p === "scissors") {
            scoreComputer += 1;
            displayComputerScore.textContent = scoreComputer;
            console.log("=================")
            console.log("Computer wins. Score of computer: " + scoreComputer);
            console.log("=================")
          } else if (c === "paper" && p === "rock") {
            scoreComputer += 1;
            displayComputerScore.textContent = scoreComputer;
            console.log("=================")
            console.log("Computer wins. Score of computer: " + scoreComputer);
            console.log("=================")
          } else if (c === "scissors" && p === "paper") {
            scoreComputer += 1;
            displayComputerScore.textContent = scoreComputer;
            console.log("=================")
            console.log("Computer wins. Score of computer: " + scoreComputer);
            console.log("=================")
          }
        };
        playRound(playerPick, computerPick);
      }
    };
    
    startButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
      game();
    });
    
    console.log("Score player: " + scorePlayer);
    console.log("Score computer: " + scoreComputer);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <title></title>
            <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
                <p>Player Score: <span id="playerScore">0</span></p>
                <p>Computer Score: <span id="computerScore">0</span></p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button id="rock" value="rock">ROCK</button>
                <button id="paper" value="paper">PAPER</button>
                <button id="scissors" value="scissors">SCISSORS</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button id="startGame">START</button>
            </div>
            <script src="script.js" async defer></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: can you also share html for this issue.

Comment: Good point! I've added the HTML at the end.

Comment: @jhavn you can add HTML, CSS and JS code at once by using the code editor (almost at the middle) of the toolbar (when writing / editing a post)

Comment: thanks @chriszo111!

Answer (score 0):

Your general problam was that returning a value in your button listeners does absolutely nothing for the game to work as intended.

```
rockButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
     //does nothing
     return playerPick = "rock";
});
```

It should instead be something like this (the functions I use, are not implemented. They are there just for the sake of a logical explanation):

```
rockButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
     playerPick = "rock";
     //get the computer's next move
     computerMove();
     //determine the winner
     calculateRoundWinner();
     //is the game finished?
     determineIfDone();
     //update the HTML to reflect the current points
     updateUI();
});
```

I understand you're a beginner, however here is "my" version of a rock, paper, scissors. Don't hesitate to point out anything that needs detailed explaining.

```js
/** order of choices are super important
* Scissors wins against paper, paper aginst rock, and rock against scissors
* Suppose: i (index of player choice) and c (index of computer choice)
* (i+1) % choices.length === c determines if player won
* (i.e: i = 0 (scissors), c = 1 (paper), ((0+1) % 3) === 1, player win
* (i.e: i = 2 (rock), c = 0 (scissors), ((2+1) % 3) === 0, player win
*/
const choices = ["scissors", "paper", "rock"];
const ps = document.getElementById("playerScore"),
      cs = document.getElementById("computerScore"),
      ds = document.getElementById("draws"),
      r  = document.getElementById("round"),
      s  = document.getElementById("startGame");

/**
* Store all relevant data in an object
*/
const data = {
  playerScore: 0,
  computerScore: 0,
  draws: 0,
  round: 0,
  running: false
}

/**
* Fancy way of adding event listeners to each of your buttons
*/
choices
.map(a=>document.getElementById(a))
.forEach((ele,i)=>ele.addEventListener("click", ()=>choiceHandler(i)));

function getComputerMove(){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
}

function choiceHandler(i){
   if(!data.running) return;
   const c = getComputerMove();
   switch(true){
      //player wins round
      case (i+1) % choices.length === c:
        data.playerScore++;
        break;
      //draw
      case i === c:
        data.draws++;
        break;
      //compuer wins round
      default:
        data.computerScore++;
  }
  //increment round everytime player makes a choice
  data.round++;
  if(data.round > 5){
    //stop the game
    data.running = false;
    //update final message of the winner
    data.round = data.playerScore > data.computerScore ? "You win" : "You lose";
  }
  updateUI();
}

function updateUI(){
  ps.innerText = data.playerScore;
  cs.innerText = data.computerScore;
  ds.innerText = data.draws;
  r.innerText  = data.round;
}

s.addEventListener("click", function(){
  //on start, set round to 1
  data.round = 1;
  //set all values to 0 (in case a previous round was played, exactly like a reset)
  data.computerScore = data.playerScore = data.draws = 0;
  data.running = true;
  updateUI();
})
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

div:first-child {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div > p {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
}

div > button {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

div > button:hover {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Round: <span id="round">0</span></p>
  <p>Player Score: <span id="playerScore">0</span></p>
  <p>Computer Score: <span id="computerScore">0</span></p>
  <p>Draws: <span id="draws">0</span></p>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="rock" value="rock">ROCK</button>
  <button id="paper" value="paper">PAPER</button>
  <button id="scissors" value="scissors">SCISSORS</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="startGame">START</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for your comment! Haven't had much time but I'll go over your code and see if I understand it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

Your `for`-loop iterates 5 times every time you click the button. Hence, once you click `START` there are "5 games played".

**Idea**

I assume that every time you click `START` you want to have one iteration, so one game round. You do *not* need a loop for that because your button already triggers your `game()` function. That does of course not mean that you can use a `for`-loop (you are free to do what you want!)

**My solution**

I [fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/rhyL5p41/) a bit, here is what I think you want to do, where I tried to change your code as less as possible (@kemicofa provided a more professional approach)

```js
var scorePlayer = parseInt(document.getElementById("playerScore").innerHTML);
var scoreComputer = parseInt(document.getElementById("computerScore").innerHTML);
let count = 0;

let rockButton = document.getElementById("rock");
let paperButton = document.getElementById("paper");
let scissorsButton = document.getElementById("scissors");
let startButton = document.getElementById("startGame");
let resetButton = document.getElementById("resetGame");
let playerPick = "";
    
let computerPlay = () => {
  const pick = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

  computerPick = pick[Math.floor(Math.random() *    pick.length)];
};

let playerPlay = () => {

  rockButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
   playerPick = 'rock';
 });
      
  paperButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    playerPick = 'paper';
  });

  scissorsButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    playerPick = 'rock';
  });

}

// playerPick = prompt("what's your pick?").toLowerCase();

// game is played for 5 rounds max

let game = () => {
    
    if (count >= 5) {
     alert('Maximum rounds played.')
    } else {
     alert(`Round ${count}`);
      
      playerPlay();
    computerPlay();
    
    let playRound = (p, c) => {
          if (p === c) {
            console.log("=================")
            console.log("Draw. PLAY AGAIN!");
            console.log("=================")
          } else if (c === "rock" && p === "paper") {
            scorePlayer++;
            document.getElementById('playerScore').innerHTML = scorePlayer;
            console.log("=================")
            console.log(`${playerPick} beats ${computerPick}. \n Player score: ${scorePlayer}`);
            console.log("=================")
          } else if (c === "paper" && p === "scissors") {
            scorePlayer += 1;
            document.getElementById('playerScore').innerHTML = scorePlayer;
            console.log("=================");
            console.log("Player wins. Player score: " + scorePlayer);
            console.log("=================");
          } else if (c === "scissors" && p === "rock") {
            scorePlayer += 1;
            document.getElementById('playerScore').innerHTML = scorePlayer;
            console.log("=================");
            console.log("Player wins. Player score: " + scorePlayer);
            console.log("=================");
          } else if (c === "rock" && p === "scissors") {
            scoreComputer += 1;
            document.getElementById('computerScore').innerHTML = scoreComputer;
            console.log("=================");
            console.log("Computer wins. Score of computer: " + scoreComputer);
            console.log("=================");
          } else if (c === "paper" && p === "rock") {
            scoreComputer += 1;
            document.getElementById('computerScore').innerHTML = scoreComputer;
            console.log("=================");
            console.log("Computer wins. Score of computer: " + scoreComputer);
            console.log("=================");
          } else if (c === "scissors" && p === "paper") {
            scoreComputer += 1;
            document.getElementById('computerScore').innerHTML = scoreComputer;
            console.log("=================");
            console.log("Computer wins. Score of computer: " + scoreComputer);
            console.log("=================");
          }
        };
        playRound(playerPick, computerPick);
    }
        count++;
    };
    
    startButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
      game();
    });
    
    resetButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
      count = 0;
      document.getElementById('playerScore').innerHTML = 0;
      document.getElementById('computerScore').innerHTML = 0;
    });
    
console.log("Score player: " + scorePlayer);
console.log("Score computer: " + scoreComputer);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <title></title>
            <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
                <p>Player Score: <span id="playerScore">0</span></p>
                <p>Computer Score: <span id="computerScore">0</span></p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button id="rock" value="rock">ROCK</button>
                <button id="paper" value="paper">PAPER</button>
                <button id="scissors" value="scissors">SCISSORS</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button id="startGame">START</button>
                <button id="resetGame">RESET</button>
            </div>
            <script src="script.js" async defer></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```